# Access Request or IQueryCollection in Layout.cshtml in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to access the `Request` or `IQueryCollection` within a view, and specifically within `_Layout.cshtml`? The reason for this is to conditionally render elements in Razor based on the query string. Obviously this isn't ideal but this is a legacy application.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access `IQueryCollection` inside of any Razor View via the [`Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.context#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_RazorPage_Context) property, which is an instance of `HttpContext`.

Here's an example:

```html
<p>
    Foo: @Context.Request.Query["Foo"]
</p>
```

For more information, see [Use HttpContext from a Razor view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0#access-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view-in-mvc)
.